# Using Chartjs 2.7.1—legend doesn't have align configuration options—how to add it?

Tags: chart.js

Javascript included below. Usually adding:

```
align: 'center',
```

Would work but 2.7.1 doesn't support it. How do I add it? I'm very new to Javascript so please be as descriptive as possible with any help! Thank you!

```
defaults._set('global', {
    legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'bottom',
        fullWidth: true,
        reverse: false,
        weight: 1000,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add it, its not in the lib, if you update to the latest version of chart.js in V2 it is there and you can use it:

If using NPM

```bash
npm i chart.js@2.9.4
```

If using yarn

```bash
yarn add chart.js@2.9.4
```